# Prove that the condition is impossible

Tags: contest-math, invariance

> There are 2004 girls sitting around a table. One of them has 2004 candies, and the others have none. On each round, every girl having more than 1 candy gives 1 candy to each girl to the left and right of her. Prove that the condition in which each girl has exactly 1 candy is impossible.

I can't even get any idea for this...
Can anyone give me hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sketch:  I would try to show that the special girl (who starts at $2004$) can only move in increments of $2$.  Indeed, she only doles out candy in increments of $2$ and if she receives a candy from her left she will also receive one from her right by symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very old problem, dating back to the year 1994, when it was asked for $1994$ girls. That one was really easy (mod $4$), because $1994$ is congruent to $2$ mod $4$.

For general even number $n$ (e.g. $n = 2004$ here), an argument mod $n$ suffices.

The interesting thing is that, if we start with an odd number of girls, then the procedure will eventually end in finitely many steps. The proof is more complicated and much more interesting than the original problem.

---

For reference: [IMO 1994 shortlist](https://prase.cz/kalva/short/sh94.html) Problem C5. Also see the remark there.

Comment: Note, however, that while it uses the same setting, Problem C5 is actually rather different from this one. <dry> And it’s mildly disconcerting to see a 1994 problem described as *old*. </dry>

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was playing super mario bros back in 1994. Is that *old*?

Comment: I’ve no experience with video games, but I’m old enough that the whole concept still feels relatively new. According to Wikipedia, Super Mario Brothers is less than half my age.